# Invisible mouse cursor in Starcraft II

Tags: starcraft-2, mouse

You can still click stuff, but it appears the mouse cursor is missing/invisible when I launch the game.

Online they say you can change the "compatibility" mode settings and fix this, but because I'm running through battle.net, it appears those changes don't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted and it fixed the problem. I had recently changed DPI & resolution settings and something wasn't sticking.

Comment: Standard first step of computer troubleshooting: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Answer (score 1):

Try using window mode (fullscreen). That worked for me.

Other solutions I read while searching for the same problem:

-Run as administrator

-Run with compatibility (Windows 7)

-Make Windows' interface smaller (right click on Desktop > Screen Resolution > Make items look smaller or bigger

Answer (score 1):

Some Blizzard titles also suffer from scaling issues with mouse cursors.

If you have any kind of "zoom" setup on your screen, found here 
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display`, anything other than "smaller 100%(default)" can cause the mouse cursor to disappear.

Comment: Tried that. No love :(

Answer (score 0):

I just had a disappearing mouse issue after the latest SC2 patch.  The problem was mouse trails.  Disabled mouse trails and cursor reappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from changing to windowed fullscreen, none of the above options worked for me on Windows 10 since the latest SCII update.  What did work was

- in Mouse Properties/Pointers untick "enable pointer shadow", and
- in Mouse Properties/Pointer Options untick "hide pointer while typing".